# how to retrieve Title from YouTube playlist using XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, youtube

here i tried the code . but it is not working . please help me

```
         <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/cZxy-GpHLCQ_Ss9sGJfWhzBAIOMDYxMN?v=2",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('feed').each(function(i){
            var sTitle = $(this).find('title');

         // alert(sTitle);
          for (var i = 0; i < sTitle.length; i++) {   
          var ssTitle = sTitle[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
          $(ssTitle).appendTo("#dvContent ul");

          }

        });
        },
        error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```

Demo Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/8HUbc/

Thanx in Advance !!

Comment: Can you please define "not working"?

Comment: it shows me alert "An error occurred while processing XML file"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cTrhU/

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
var sTitle = $(this).find('title');
```

Just do:

```
sTitle.text();
```

And you'll have it.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is failing (this has nothing to do with processing your XML file). The error callback is *not* like a `try/catch` block around your success function, it is an indication that either the server returned something other than a 200 or so response code or there was no response from the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try narrow the search with `feed` children nodes only:

```
var title = $(xml).find('feed > title').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wY55/